# Preloader screen with outlined structure of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Refering to this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF2Hb.png), what technology or language used to execute the preloader screen of websites in such an outlined structure fashion? All the elements execute a sweep shine while loading.

Given website is www.youtube.com,this is also found on facebook, amazon, medium etc.

Please suggest how to get started in this?

Comment: does this solve your query?

Comment: yes, it does. Thanks.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."  I did it several times- but this pops up:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called shimmer. You can make a shimmer using HTML and CSS. You show shimmer until your data loads and hide/remove it using javascript. Below is a sample code.

```css
body{ 
   border: 2px solid #f6f7f8;
  padding: 100px; 
}

.shine {
  background: #f6f7f8;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f6f7f8 0%, #edeef1 20%, #f6f7f8 40%, #f6f7f8 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 800px 104px; 
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; 
  
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: placeholderShimmer;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  }

box {
  height: 104px;
  width: 100px;
}

div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  vertical-align: top; 
}

lines {
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px; 
}

photo {
  display: block!important;
  width: 325px; 
  height: 100px; 
  margin-top: 15px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes placeholderShimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: -468px 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    background-position: 468px 0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<box class="shine"></box>

<div>
<lines class="shine"></lines>
<lines class="shine"></lines>
<lines class="shine"></lines>
</div>

<photo class="shine"></photo>
<photo class="shine"></photo>

<br>

<box class="shine"></box>

<div>
<lines class="shine"></lines>
<lines class="shine"></lines>
<lines class="shine"></lines>
</div>
```